# Prepared String Before Comma

Tags: php, preg-match

I've got an array;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Test1
    [1] => Test2
    [2] => Test3
)
```

Now I've used the Implode Function from which i got the comma separated String: 
Test1, Test2, Test3

now I'd like to put a quotes ("") before and after every word e.g. 
"Test1", "Test2", "Test3"

How could I change it to work how I want.

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple one-liner:

```
$quotedStrings = '"' . implode('","', $myArray) . '"';
```

The "`glue`" parameter may be a complex string, though you only have to put the `"` at the beginning and end.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer from Axel is totally fine for the given szenario,
using `array_map` along with `implode` will also work.

And this has the advantage, that modifications to each element are not limited to the start/end of the element. For instance, you can turn each entry to lower-case as well, or perform other, more complex operations, before applying `implode`.

```
$quotedString = implode(",", array_map("myCallback", $myArray));

function myCallback($entry){
   //here you can to whatever you like to EACH element.
   return '"'.$entry.'"';
}
```

Consider this an *option*

Comment: One more nice way to do it + 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use make a new array by using foreach loop and then use implode. Use the code below

```
<?php
$array = array("Test1","Test2","Test3");

$quotes = array();
foreach($array as $p){
$quotes[] = '"'.$p.'"';
}
echo implode(",",$quotes); // Outputs "Test1","Test2","Test3"
?>
```

Another way you can do it by enclosing the implode in `""` quotes and then implode comma `,` in quotes.

```
<?php
    $array = array("Test1","Test2","Test3");


    echo '"'.implode('","',$array).'"'; // Outputs "Test1","Test2","Test3"
    ?>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: It works, the "-1" is for the claim "you will have to" - cause there are other, easier, options.

Comment: @dognose Edited my answer remove the downvote please

Comment: but where is the explode you are using *first* ? :-P